# How to give a presentation parts of which require VPN and parts do not?

Tags: networking, vpn, remote-desktop

I need to broadcast a GoToMeeting which demoes several technologies. Some of these should be available locally, others require a VPN. The problem is that when I connect to the VPN, GoToMeeting goes crazy and doesn't connect to the audio service.

So my question is: is there any way I can set up a command-line VPN session that doesn't go outside the bounds of the console, i.e. doesn't change my machine's IP address or anything like that? I thought of doing it via Remote Desktop or a VM but realized that neither of these two approaches will work.

Comment: Any method you use will cause this problem because the underline problem is with GoToMeeting and the VPN itself.  The method you go about connecting to the VPN won't change that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I have VPN issues using something locally like gotomeeting its because the VPN has a setting in its advanced properties stating use remote gateway (basically pushing all traffic down the VPN). If you disable this does gotomeeting still have the issue?